# What is a non-encoding lossless h.264 AVC editor? (other than avidemux which is buggy)

Tags: editing, avchd

This is actually in reference to mp4 h264 avc shadowplay videos; I've tried avidemux but its buggy, and alternatively I like shotcut's interface but it doesn't have the specialized h264 in/out lossless cutting without encoding like avidemux.

Comment: If you specify the bugs you've experienced, it would help. Otherwise your post read a bit like a rant against avidemux.

Answer (score 2):

I know only [VideoReDo](http://www.videoredo.com/en/index.htm) and [SolveigMM Video Splitter](http://vegasaur.com/SolveigMM-Video-Splitter), but they are not full-featured video editors. Both are not free.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the encoding through `ffmpeg` with `-crf 0`, for Shotcut see instructions in the faq under [Where are the log presets, database, and settings stored](http://www.shotcut.org/bin/view/Shotcut/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#Where_are_the_log_presets_databa)